# Meaning and nuance of 詰む / 詰まる

Tags: grammar, meaning, nuances

I have some difficulties to understand the meaning of 詰む in the context

> あなたとは違{ちが}ってね」　 
>   冷静{れいせい}に返{かえ}されオレは言葉{ことば}を**詰{つ}まらせた**。
>
> I am different from you. She returned my words calmly and "*I was
>   checkmated / I was at loss" ??*

the dictionary gives for

> 詰む (shogi) to be checkmated;  to be hard pressed; to be at a loss; to
>   reach the limits;

but I cannot figure the meaning of 詰む in the context and its association with 言葉

By the way, I am aware the Causative-Passive form (to force something on somebody) is used. 
Does it alter significantly the use of 詰む ?

Comment: Look up 詰まる in a dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok

I made a mistake: I thought that the **passive causative** form was used with 詰む.

But in fact, the verb was 詰まる **with the causative** and the dictionary gives:

> 言葉{ことば}に詰{つ}まる　(exp,v5r) to be at a loss for words